# Global data array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array like this

```
  $meta = array(
       'meta_description' => 'lorem ipsum',
       'meta_keywords' => 'this, is, a, keyword'
  );
```

If I have this in my controller method, I can pass it to a partial like so:        `$this->template->set_partial('header', 'layouts/header', $meta)` and it passes fine.

I store the meta tags in the database, so I'd ideally like to put it in MY_Controller and populate the array based on the database values for that post's meta tags.

If I move it outside of the controller method, I get `Message: Undefined variable: meta`
 as an error.

How can I make it globally available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

I just created a new model for handling meta data, then I insert the following into MY_Controller's construct method:

```
 $meta = $this->meta_data_model->get_item_meta();

 $this->template->set_partial('header', 'layouts/header', $meta);
```

This seems to work fine, not sure if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you want to access globally should be stored in the user session:

```
$this->load->library('session'); // Unless auto loaded
$this->session->set_userdata('meta', $meta);
```

Then retrieve it where you need it:

```
$meta = $this->session->userdata('meta');
```

Comment: Isn't that for storing information about the user? This isn't related to users.

Comment: I dont think this is the best use of the userdata as it does not relate directly to the user and userdata can only store up to 4KB

Comment: Agreed. Userdata isn't the best given what he's trying to do.